# Prepared for Yet Another Simple Rebus?

Tags: rebus

**Solve this simple rebus.**

[image]

**???**

It is quite simple and I guess it will be answered within a few minutes.  :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The answer is :

> Are you ready?

Because :

> Well, @MOehm already explained the **R** and the **U** faster than me so I won't do it twice (but *do* upvote his answer as well!). This gives us two letters. The last letter is a big E in red - **red E** - **ready**.

Hence the answer:

> **R** - **U** - **red E** : **Are you ready?**

Comment: [AYE-AYE, CAPTAIN!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He-LBIyBUz8)

Comment: Okay, didn't really see that, although it's obvious now. `:(`

Comment: @MOehm The last term was the first thing I found, lol. Then I found the *R*, the second currency, and your answer popped up... A regular day on PSE I guess :-)

Comment: Oh, that's okay. What bugs me is that I couldn't make the mental leap from RU to "Are you". My excuse is that it's Friday and that I don't text very often.

Answer (score 29):

I think this may be

> **RUE**.
>
>  The top image is a South Arican **RAND** note, from which the shape of an [**AND** gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate#Symbols) has been cut, leaving **R**. The middle image is a [**URIAL** sheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urial), from which an Iranian **RIAL** is subtracted, leaving **U**. And the bottom image is the Latin letter **E**.
>
>  (There may well be more to it. For example the E may be a RED E, but I can't find anything that fits. Or maybe the E stands for a third currency?)

Comment: what is the meaning  of Rue?

Comment: @lois6b Regret, only moreso

Comment: @lois6b Street in French. :D